# VSCode does not use nautilus to open a file or folder

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, nautilus

I don't like the interface that I see when I try to open a file or a folder, the navigation bar are simple texts all together and it hinders its use, is there any way to change it appearance or use nautilus?

My system is as follows:

Ubuntu: 18.10

VSCode: 1.31.1

[image: VSCode Open folder image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please provide what `cat /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | grep inode/directory` is returning?

Comment: Of course: `inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;`

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Does VSCode execute Nautilus when you right click on a file and select `Open Containing Folder`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably [this post on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44344) may help you to find a solution?

Comment: I don't have the "Open containg folder" option when I right click on a folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will post it on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the next day since I posted, I don't do nothing but when I turn on my computer vscode starts to use nautilus correctly. I don't know why it happens but, if you have the same problem, maybe [this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44344) help you.

[VSCode using nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPbE3.png)